# OpenGL ES 2.0: Using glBufferData with new vertex data size

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, vertex

I have an array of vertex attributes `GLfloat *vxData`. I've bound both `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` and `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` with `vxData` and the correct index data, and the initial vertices render successfully.

At each render step I do:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vxDataSize, vxData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glDrawElements(...)
```

At some stage, `vxData` changes size to accommodate fewer/more vertices, the index data is recreated to reflect this, and `vxDataSize` is updated. For the render immediately following this change in data, is it correct to simply call the same lines above?

I'm aware of alternative possibilities e.g. using `glMapBufferOES`, I'd simply like to know whether the above is technically correct for this scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it correct? Yes, you can do that and you should get functional code that renders what you expect it to. Is it *good*?

No.

First, you're lying to the OpenGL implementation. You told it that you were making STATIC data. STATIC means you upload to it *once*. If you're doing that every frame, then you should be using STREAM, not STATIC.

Second, you should not be making buffers bigger and smaller. It's one thing to flush the old data out, but if you're telling OpenGL that the buffer needs to be bigger, then it has to actually allocate memory. That's not good. Pick a size and stick with it. Pick the largest size you can expect to use and stay there.

Comment: Many thanks for this insight, Nicol. To achieve your second suggestion, presumably I modify `vxDataSize` to be an upper bound and simply provide index data for the vertices which exist? How should I approach this given that `vxData` is stored in RAM and needs to be as small as possible?

Comment: To clarify: I store `vxData` outside the GPU and resubmit upon each render since it contains some values that are expensive to calculate. Storing in RAM lets me adjust certain values with deltas, without recalculating from scratch.

Comment: Do you think that making `vxDataSize` dynamic, making it bigger one frame and smaller the next, is saving you memory, even in RAM? You're fragmenting your address space. If you made it a fixed size, then you would just get one chunk of memory that never moved or resized itself. If it's variable size, then you have to reallocate it when you make it bigger or smaller. That can move it around your address space and fragment it. This is not good.

Comment: In general, I find that it is best to pick a higher value that is an upper limit on memory usage, than to allow variable sized memory usage and hope you don't fragment your heap or get a perfect storm of circumstances that make you run out of memory on rare occasions.

Comment: I don't claim to be an expert, I came to C/C++ from a Java background so have had to learn memory management along the way. Thanks for the detailed explanation, I appreciate your advice. I'll make `vxData` be a fixed upper bound size now, then pass only the indices I need.

Comment: I agree with Nicol Bolas about his concerns with address space fragmentation. However this is only half of the story. Modern OS manage memory in pages. A page is the smallest amount of memory you actually can allocate. The runtime library will allocate smaller objects from within one page. But if you make your allocations exactly one page in size, then you can allocate and free as often as you like, and will not fragment your process' address space.

Comment: In my programs I tend to reserves big chunks of memory, for each class of structure one chunk, which holds up to N instances of that structure. "Allocating" memory for one such structure is finding the next free slot in the chunk. If one such chunk is exhausted, another one is allocated. Such single time allocations are rather cheap.

Comment: What works for CPU side structures works as well for GPU structures. For example small props found in a game (soda cans, trash, stuff like that), are placed into one single VBO. Using the right calls to glVertexAttribPointer those "chunks" are selected. But one can also work with index offsets and similar.

Comment: Thanks for that expansive information datenwolf! Can I ask you for one clarification from Nicol's comments: following his advice, presumably I should be allocating my index data only once as well, and thereafter pass to `glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER..)` an index data size reflecting the number of indices I wish to use? I just want to check I've got the new design right :)